# Error initializing object. Can't set value to PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, properties, null

I can't figure out why I am unable to set the value of an instance of `PFObject`.  It is working successfully elsewhere in the app, but I must be doing something wrong in this view.  I'd really appreciate your help figuring out what I'm missing.  Thanks.

Basically

```
self.ABC.type = @"Frustrated";
NSLog(@"why is this null? -----> %@",self.ABC.type);
2015-10-18 18:26:29.277 XX [885:109003] why is this null?  -----> (null)
```

Why is the value not being assigned?  It should log as ... `I'm not null or frustrating... I'm working, see  -----> Frustrated  !!!!!!`  but it is not working!

I'm therefore unable to set the object in Parse bc it's nil and the app crashes.

Below should be all and more of the code you need, but let me know it you have questions or suggestions.  Thanks!:

**FCollectionViewController.m:**

```
#import "FCollectionViewController.h"
#import "FCell.h"
#import "SectionHeaderView.h"

#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

#import "Helper.h"

@interface FCollectionViewController()
 <UICollectionViewDelegate, MBProgressHUDDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *presetsDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *presets;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *textViewIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FCell *fCell;

@property (nonatomic, strong) MBProgressHUD *HUD;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *headTitleArray;

@end

@implementation FCollectionViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.headTitleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"type",
                           @"model",
                           @"feature", nil];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Presets"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
            [keys addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"key"]];
            [values addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"value"]];
        }
        self.presetsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

        self.presets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            [self.presetsDictionary objectForKey:@"type"],
                            [self.presetsDictionary objectForKey:@"model"],
                            [self.presetsDictionary objectForKey:@"feature"],nil];
        NSLog(@"self.presets ----> %@", self.presets);
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return [self.presets count];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  [self.presets[section] count];
}

- (UICollectionReusableView*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView * view = nil;

    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader])
    {
        ItemSectionHeaderView *header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader                                                      withReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([ItemSectionHeaderView class])
                                                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
        header.captionLabel.text = self.headTitleArray[indexPath.section];
        view = header;
    }
    return view;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell;

    FCell *aCell = (FCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"fCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    aCell.label.text = self.presets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    aCell.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell = aCell;
    return cell;
}



- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize size;
     ....
    return size;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSArray * selectedRows = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;

  for (NSIndexPath * selectedRow in selectedRows) {
    if ((selectedRow.section == indexPath.section) && (selectedRow.row != indexPath.row)) {
      [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:selectedRow animated:NO];
    }
  }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
      self.aBC.type = @"Frustrated";
      NSLog(@"why isn't this being assigned? -----> %@",self.ABC.type);
      break;
    case 1:
      self.aBC.model = self.presets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
      NSLog(@"why is this null?!!!! -----> %@",self.ABC.model);
      NSLog(@"this DOES log the value I want!! -----> %@",self.presets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]);
      break;
    case 2:
      ...
    default:
      break;
    }
}
```

**FCollectionViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ABC.h"

@interface FCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
//<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property (nonatomic, strong) ABC *aBC;
@end
```

**ABC.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ABC : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *model;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *feature;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *pfObj;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *user;

- (id)initWithPFObject:(PFObject *)anObject;

@end
```

**ABC.m:**

```
#import "ABC.h"

@implementation ABC

- (id)initWithPFObject:(PFObject *)anObject
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        [anObject fetchIfNeeded];
        self.pfObj = anObject;
        self.type = [anObject objectForKey:@"type"];
        self.model = [anObject objectForKey:@"model"];
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**FCell.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

**FCell.m:**

```
#import "FCell.h"

@implementation FCell

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
  self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
  self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where you are initializing ABC object ?

Comment: He isn't. Just saw your comment after posing my answer, but I'll delete mine if you post yours.

Comment: Thanks @pawan.  You're right but I am unsure where/how to.  I'm getting error when attempting to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aBC isn't initialized anywhere. You declare it, but it isn't initialized. So setting aBC.type isn't actually setting anything.

Add `self.aBC = [[ABC alloc] init];` in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks Jake.  You're right, I guess I'm not, but I can't figure out the syntax for doing it either.  Adding aBC = new ABC(); as you suggest I get the warning:

Comment: pre-emptive post....  full comment  Thanks Jake.  You're right, I guess I'm not, but I can't figure out the syntax for doing it either.  Adding aBC = new ABC(); as you suggest I get the warning: "Use of undeclared identifier 'aBC' did you mean '_aBC'?" It I change to _aBC I get the warning "Use of undeclared identifier 'new'.  which seems like a C++ vs objective c issue.  If I instead write   ABC *aBC =  [[ABC alloc]init];  I get the warning "Unused variable aBC"

Comment: Ahh, sorry. It should be _aBC = [[ABC alloc] init]; or _aBC = [ABC new];  Wrong syntax, been helping a friend with C++.  I'll edit my answer.  The last method you tried isn't working because you're defining a new local instance of aBC, and your method is using the property.  _aBC = [ABC new]; may not work either... I've never tried it with a custom class, so I'm not sure if it will still automatically call [[ABC alloc] init]; , though I think it will since you can do that with PFObject and ABC inherits from PFObject.

Comment: Thanks Jake.  yes, _aBC = [[ABC alloc] init]; worked. As does:                       - (ABC *)aBC
{
    if (!_aBC) {
        _aBC = [[ABC alloc] init];
    }
    return _aBC;
}